Why doesn't the window appear right away?
It is necessary to make the window appear simultaneously with the start of the sound signal. But in my example, the sound signal is triggered first and only after it the window appears.
from tkinter import *
import winsound
 
window = Tk()            
window.title("Test")     
window.geometry("200x50")   

def myfunc():
    winsound.Beep(500,3000)
    
window.after(0, myfunc)
window.mainloop()

How can I make these two events work simultaneously? So that the window appears simultaneously with the sound signal?

Change window.after(0, ...) to window.after(1, ...).

Does winsound.Beep block code execution until it is done?

In your code the line window.after(0, myfunc) blocks the code until it has finished which is why your code doesn't show the window (window.mainloop()) until the sound has finished. To fix this you can use the Threading module to continue running the code instead of blocking.
from tkinter import *
import winsound
import threading
 
window = Tk()            
window.title("Test")     
window.geometry("200x50")   

def myfunc():
    winsound.Beep(500,3000)

threading.Thread(target=myfunc).start() 
window.mainloop()

